# Is $f: (0,\infty ) \to \mathbb{R}$ , $f(x):=\ln(x)+e^x$ injective?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, logarithms, exponential-function, monotone-functions

i showed that $f$ is strictly monotonically increasing:

$\ln(x+1)+e^{x+1} > \ln (x)+e^x$

Both $\ln$ and $\exp$ are monotonically increasing function, this inequaltiy is obviously true, or do I have to prove that fact?

Comment: @FengShao Technically, the one he wrote isn't.

Comment: Functions of real variable $\neq$ sequences. You need to show that $x>y \implies \ln x + e^x > \ln y + e^y$.

Comment: isn't that true? $x>y \Leftrightarrow \ln(x) > \ln(y) \Leftrightarrow \ln x + e^x > \ln y + e^y$

Comment: Of course it is true, but $f(x+1)>f(x),$ for all $x$, doesn't imply $f(x) > f(y)$, for all $x>y$, as the answer by José Carlos Santos shows.

Comment: Would what I have written be enough?

Comment: To be technically precise, I would write it like: $x>y \implies (\ln x > \ln y \ \text{and}\ e^x > e^y)$, so $x>y \implies \ln x + e^x > \ln y + e^x > \ln y + e^y$, where we use that $e^x$ and $\ln x$ are monotonically increasing and also the axiom $a>b\implies a + c> b + c$ (notice that we use it twice).

Comment: Well if $a > b$ and $c > d$ then $a +c > b+d$.  That's basic and probably doesn't need to be shown.  If you need to prove that $a > b$ then $a+c > b+c$ but ordered field axioms.  And by the same axiom if $c > d$ then $b+c > b+d$.  And by transitivity $a+c > b+c$ and $b+c > b+d$ implies $a+c > b+d$.  But *surely* you don't need to prove things in that much detail.

Comment: @fleablood, this seems like a question from the first course in analysis, and you are completely right, but who knows what kind of detail is expected. I just wanted to point out what precisely is used, OP can decide for themselves or ask professor.

Comment: Another example could be $f(x) = x + \sin(2\pi x)$  $f(x+1) = (x+1) + \sin [(x+1)2\pi]  = x + \sin [2\pi x] + 1 =f(x) + 1 > f(x)$ but $f(\frac 14 = \frac 14 + \sin \frac pi 2= 1\frac 14$ but $f(\frac 12) = \frac 12 + \sin \pi = \frac 12$ and $f(\frac 34) = \frac 34 + \sin\frac {3\pi}2 = -\frac 14$.

Comment: @Ennar I hadn't seen your comment when I wrote the exact same thing. So my comment wasn't meant to critique yours.  A first year analysis course usually gets those properties out of the way in the first day or so.  By the time we get to answering the question then claiming "$e^{x+1} + \ln(x+1) > e^x + \ln x$ because both exp and log functions are both strictly increasing" is thorough enough for anyone.

Comment: It's actually unclear what your post is trying to say.  You ask a question in the title that is never mentioned in the body.  You say you showed $f$ is strictly monotonically increasing.  You then claim that $f(x+1) > f(x)$ but you don't say that that is a result of $f$ being increasing (it's valid) or the reason $f$ is strictly monotonically increasing (not valid).  Then you say $ln$, $exp$ are strictly increasing which is enough to prove the $f(x+1) > f(x)$ statement but its unclear if you still want to prove that and if so, why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take$$\begin{array}{rccc}f\colon&\mathbb R&\longrightarrow&\mathbb R\\&x&\mapsto&\begin{cases}x+1&\text{ if }x\in\mathbb Z\\x&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}\end{array}$$Then $(\forall x\in\mathbb R):f(x+1)>f(x)$. However, $f$ is **not** monotonically increasing.

It is more natural to deduce that your function is monotonically increasing from the fact that it is the sum of two monotonically increasing functions.

Comment: Should I show $f'(x) >0 $ instead?

Comment: You can do that. Or you can say that, if $y>x$, then$$e^y=e^{y-x+x}=e^{y-x}e^x>e^x$$(since $y-x>0$) and that$$\ln(y)=\ln\left(\frac yx\times x\right)=\ln\left(\frac yx\right)+\ln(x)>\ln(x)$$(since $\frac yx>1$).

Comment: Thanks a million!

Comment: I'm glad I could help.